# The usage of MapIndexed, can it be removed?

Tags: functional-style, project-euler

[project euler 67](https://projecteuler.net/problem=67)

When I'm solving this problem, my solution is as following. You can download the data file there.

```
file = "G:\\Documents\\Mathematica\\MyPE\\51-100\\p067_triangle.txt";

fileImported = 

  Import[file, "Data"] // StringSplit /@ # & // Flatten // ToExpression;

len = Length[fileImported];

partition[list_, pos_] := 

 Module[{}, (pos1 = Prepend[Accumulate@pos, 0];

   res = Take[list, {1, 0} + #] & /@ Partition[pos1, 2, 1])]

numberList1 = partition[fileImported, Range[100]];

numberList1[[1 ;; 4]]

(*
    {{59},{73,41},{52,40,9},{26,53,6,34}}
*)

numberList = MapIndexed[f[#2, #1] &, #] & /@ numberList1;

pickMax[trackList_] := MaximalBy[trackList, Total[#[[All, 2]]] &, 1]

trackUpdate[trackList_] := 

 GroupBy[trackList, Last] // KeySortBy[#, #[[1, 1]] &] & // Values // 

   pickMax /@ # & // Flatten[#, 1] & /@ # &

track[1] = {numberList[[1]]};

track[n_] := Module[{parts, trackAll}, (

   parts = Partition[numberList[[n]], 2, 1];

   (trackAll = 

Map[Flatten, (Thread[#, List, {2}] & /@ 

    Thread[{track[n - 1], parts}]), {2}] // Flatten[#, 1] &);

   (*按节点，聚合路径，按照路径的和，把路径数减少为节点数，比如第三层4条变成3条，47处两条路径共用了一个节点，第四层，6条变成4条。

   Pick the track with largest sum ends up with the same nodes*)

   trackUpdate[trackAll]

   )]

res100 = track[100];

Table[res100[[i, All, 2]] // Total, {i, Length@res100}] // Max;
```

My question is about the usage of MapIndexed, can it be removed? `Here` in this way, One can not use a index like that sow in a Do/For loop.
and further, along my thread, how can I optimize my codes?

And if we just use numberList1, then in two different positions of one row of the triangle, the numbers may be the same, this will affect the usage of `GroupBy` in trackUpdate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numberListIndexed=partition[Thread[{Range[len],fileImported}],Range[100]];
numberIndexList=#[[All,1]]&/@numberListIndexed;
numberListAsso=AssociationThread[Range[len],fileImported];
pickMax[trackList_]:=MaximalBy[trackList,Total[Map[numberListAsso,#, {1}]]&,1]
append[x_,y_]:=Append[x,#]&/@y
trackExtend[trackList_]:=Block[{len},len=Length@trackList;
Flatten[MapThread[append,{trackList,Partition[numberIndexList[[len+1]],2,1]}],1]]
reduceTrack[trackList_]:=Flatten[Values@GroupBy[trackList,Last,pickMax],1]
trackUpdate[trackList_]:=reduceTrack[trackExtend[trackList]]
trackListAll=Nest[trackUpdate,{{1}},99];
Total/@Map[numberListAsso,trackListAll,{2}]//Max
7273
```

This is not an efficient solution, but along my first thread I think it's clean and better than the version in question and without use of `MapIndexed`.

Answer (score 10):

It's quite easy once you realize that the bottom-up max sums give you the desired result:

```
i = Reverse@Import["https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p067_triangle.txt", "Table"];
f[linPrev_, lin_] := Max /@ (lin + Partition[linPrev, 2, 1])
Fold[f, i]

(* {7273} *)
```

Comment: `Import["tri.txt", 
  "Table"] //. {x___, a_, b_} :> {x, a + Max /@ Partition[b, 2, 1]}` was my solution about ten years ago. ( Now I feel old. :-( )

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for posting this and other similarly beautiful solutions in the project euler forum. This solution particularly impressed me, because it's so terse and super fast (unexpectedly fast, as it's base on `ReplaceRepeated`).

Comment: @Karsten7 I am glad you like this (and others)!  Thanks for letting me know. :-)  I think I have learned a lot since those days but Project Euler was probably the first time I made a concerted effort to write "nice" code.

Answer (score 6):

A top-down approach:

```
triangle = Import["https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p067_triangle.txt", "Table"];
listmod[l_List] := {First@l} ~Join~ Partition[l, 2, 1] ~Join~ {Last@l}
mainF[lastList_List, nextList_List] := Max /@ Inner[Plus, listmod[lastList], nextList, List]
Max@Fold[mainF, triangle[[1]], triangle[[2 ;;]]]
```

> ```
> 7273
> ```

Comment: I've stolen your import format :), Thanks